# Shared Preferences - Should I store key values as strings? Possible bad practice

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using shared preferences and am a bit unsure on what the best practice is on what data type to store key value pairs.

Example: I have a spinner with 3 drop down options: `apple, banana, orange`

In my spinner, I select the option `orange` and save it to shared preferences with the key `KEY_SPINNER_FRUIT_OPTION` what data type should the value be? Currently I'm saving it as Strings

`orange`

Would it be better to use `Integer` instead?

`String lastSelectedSpinnerOption = getSharedPref().getLastSavedValue("KEY_SPINNER_FRUIT_OPTION");`

```
if(lastSelectedSpinnerOption.equals("orange")){
   mSpinner.setSelection(2);
}
```

or

`Integer lastSelectedSpinnerOption = getSharedPref().getLastSavedValue("KEY_SPINNER_FRUIT_OPTION");`

```
if(lastSelectedSpinnerOption == 2){
   mSpinner.setSelection(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well there's no any best practice as on what type you should write in `SharedPreferences` (as long as it is an accepted type for the API).

It actually totally depends on what you will do with this value.
If your goal is to save UI state and you're ***absolutely*** sure that the retained position will hold the same `String` value, you could save the `Integer`.

But I'd rather save the `String` value as it is the user's intention to select an "orange" and when it is time to restore the UI state, I'd look for the position matching the "orange" value.

Answer (score 2):

If you will store `Integer` your code won't be maintanable. If you change positions of elements(or add new element in saved position) in Spinner, your code won't work as expected.

What you can do is storing string value of chosen item into `SharedPrefs` and then:

```
int position = adapter.getPosition(myValueFromSharedPrefs);
position = position > 0 ? position : 0; // if this element was removed, choose first item of the list
mSpinner.setSelection(position);
```